# Program is not painting the GUI when called

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paint

I am a high school student trying to teach myself GUI basics.  The program I am trying to write would take two numbers from the user and then plot those two numbers in a graph.  The user can also enter more points if he or she likes.  The problem I am having is that when I press the button that opens the GUI that should be the graph, the GUI appears but it is blank.  I think there is an issue with the paint method and the way that is being set up and called but I am not sure. Thanks in advance for any advice or help.

This is the class that creates the graph GUI:

```
package dataGraph;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class graphGUI extends JFrame {
//public Graphics2D g2;
public graphGUI() {
    setTitle("Data Graph");
    setSize(500, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.drawLine(40, 425, 450, 425);
    g.drawLine(40, 425, 40, 70);
    g.drawString("Graph", 20, 20);
    // g2.draw
    g.drawLine(50, 50, 50, 50);
     for(int i = 0; i < dataEntryGUI.x.size(); i++){
     g.drawOval(Integer.parseInt(dataEntryGUI.x.get(i)),
     Integer.parseInt(dataEntryGUI.y.get(i)),5,5);
     }
}

}
```

This is the class that creates the GUI for data entry and has the action listener that allows the user to add more "points" and then "graph" them:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class dataEntryGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public static ArrayList<String> x;
public static ArrayList<String> y;

private Button btnAdd;
private Button btnGraph;
private Label lbl;
private Label lbl2;
private TextField xInt;
private TextField yInt;

public dataEntryGUI() {
    setTitle("Data entry");
    setSize(250, 250);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    lbl = new Label("x");

    lbl2 = new Label("y");

    // text fields
    xInt = new TextField();

    yInt = new TextField();
    x = new ArrayList<String>();
    y = new ArrayList<String>();

    // add button
    btnAdd = new Button("Add another");
    // btnAdd.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70,30));
    btnAdd.addActionListener(this);
    btnGraph = new Button("Make Graph");
    btnGraph.addActionListener(this);
    add(lbl);
    add(xInt);
    add(lbl2);
    add(yInt);
    add(btnAdd);
    add(btnGraph);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    // System.out.println("boogers");

    if (e.getSource() == btnAdd) {
        //xInt.getText();

        x.add(xInt.getText());
        y.add(yInt.getText());
        xInt.setText("");
        yInt.setText("");

    } else {
        graphGUI graph = new graphGUI();
        graph.repaint();
    }
}

}
```

And this is the main method:

```
package dataGraph;
public class dataGraphMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    dataEntryGUI gui = new dataEntryGUI();
    //graphGUI gui2 = new graphGUI();

}

}
```

Comment: `graphGUI graph = new graphGUI();` - what do you currently think this does?

Comment: I believe it opens the graphGUI which I named graph.

Comment: It does not. It declares a variable called `graph` (of type `graphGUI`), creates a new graphGUI, and stores a reference to it in that variable.

Comment: Don't use `static` as a means for cross communication between classes, this is not what it should be used for and could cause no end of issues.

Comment: @immibis Actually, since the OP called `setVisible` within the classes constructor, it does...

Comment: You're also mixing heavy weight (AWT) and light weight (Swing) components, this can lead to unexpected painting issues and is generally best avoided, instead, stick to Swing (`J*`) components

Comment: When I get rid of static I come up with more errors. @MadProgrammer

Comment: You need to pass a reference of the data you want to paint to the other class, this decouples the two classes and allows you to create more, different, graphs if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by camickr, some refactoring should be done. Perhaps this will help.

First, you are trying to repaint the JFrame. This is not recommended. What you want to do is define a JPanel to work on and add it to the frame's pane content.

I refactored your code a bit, so that GraphGUI is now a JPanel, and not a JFrame. This way, you can use it as a component in any future JFrame you might create.

Second, I defined a function within DataEntryGUI that creates a new frame, which will hold the graph component and paint it. Here's the complete code:

---

**Class GraphGUI**

---

```
package dataGraph;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class graphGUI extends JPanel {

    public GraphGUI() {

        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawLine(40, 425, 450, 425);
        g.drawLine(40, 425, 40, 70);
        g.drawString("Graph", 20, 20);
        g.drawLine(50, 50, 50, 50);

        for(int i = 0; i < dataEntryGUI.x.size(); i++){
            g.drawOval(Integer.parseInt(dataEntryGUI.x.get(i)),
                    Integer.parseInt(dataEntryGUI.y.get(i)),5,5);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**DataEntryGUI**

---

```
package dataGraph;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DataEntryGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public static ArrayList<String> x;  //This should be figured out by
    public static ArrayList<String> y;  //the OP. Encapsulation and
                                        //decoupling is a different matter.

    private Button btnAdd;
    private Button btnGraph;
    private Label lbl;
    private Label lbl2;
    private TextField xInt;
    private TextField yInt;


    public DataEntryGUI() {
        setTitle("Data entry");
        setSize(250, 250);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        lbl = new Label("x");

        lbl2 = new Label("y");

        // text fields
        xInt = new TextField();

        yInt = new TextField();
        x = new ArrayList<String>();
        y = new ArrayList<String>();

        // add button
        btnAdd = new Button("Add another");
        // btnAdd.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70,30));
        btnAdd.addActionListener(this);
        btnGraph = new Button("Make Graph");
        btnGraph.addActionListener(this);
        add(lbl);
        add(xInt);
        add(lbl2);
        add(yInt);
        add(btnAdd);
        add(btnGraph);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // System.out.println("boogers");

        if (e.getSource() == btnAdd) {
            //xInt.getText();

            x.add(xInt.getText());
            y.add(yInt.getText());
            xInt.setText("");
            yInt.setText("");

        } else {
            paintGraph();
        }
    }

    private void paintGraph() {
        JFrame graphFrame = new JFrame();
        GraphGUI graph = new GraphGUI();
        graphFrame.getContentPane().add(graph);

        graphFrame.setTitle("Data Graph");
        graphFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        graphFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        graphFrame.setResizable(false);
        graphFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

This seems to exhibit the behavior you wanted. I have some thoughts/comments on how you pass your x,y data (and the fact that they are public and not private), but this is beyond the scope of what you needed here.

Comment: Calling setSize on a component is pointless, as the component will likely be under the control of a layout manager. Why are you maintaining a reference to the Graphics context? That's a really bad idea and could encourage painting outside of the paint cycle, which could cause a bunch of other issues. Static, static, bloody static. I know it's what the op did, but if you're going to "suggest" a fix, then suggest one that actually encourages good habits. Oh and class naming conventions...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Alright, I followed your advice and fixed  my "suggestion". I was trying to keep the code as similar as possible to the OP's code so he could focus on the changes. But I was not aware that it is a bad idea to keep a reference to the Graphics context. So thanks, I appreciate your help

Comment: @MadProgrammer Also, as you already mentioned in your response to the op, in order to get rid of static, he will have to pass x,y arrays to the graph component. I have a version of his code doing that, but this is something the op should address himself after he solves _this_ issue.

Comment: Yeah, but the op obviously doesn't recognize the risk that static presents

Comment: Well, hopefully, he'll be interested enough to ask about it.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
```

In general, whenever you override a method you should be invoking "super" on the method name you are overriding, not some other method. That is in this case you would invoke:

```
super.paint(g);
```

However, for custom painting you should NOT override the paint() method of a JFrame.

Instead you should override the `paintComponent(...)` method of a JPanel and then add the panel to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples.

> I am a high school student trying to teach myself GUI basics.

Keep a link to the Table of Contents of the Swing tutorial handy for future reference as the tutorial covers the basics and more.